# Maven Chronos plugin

Tags: maven-2, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a problem with Maven Chronos plugin. Is it possible to tell plugin a mask for name of jmx files to execute?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a problem with Maven Chronos plugin. Is it possible to tell plugin a mask for name of jmx files to execute?

No, this is currently not supported, the chronos plugin is limited to process only one `.jmx/.jtl` that you must "hard code" in the POM. But an issue has been logged as [MOJO-1460](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1460) to enhance the plugin and make it able to process multiple scenario. It's not exactly what you're asking for but it might provide a decent alternative (and there is a patch attached).

---

> Do you know if I can run multiple jmeter tests with any other plugin?

I double checked and it appears that the [maven-jmeter-plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin) can do that (and even supports includes and excludes if required).

A more recent version of the plugin (using JMeter 2.3) was hosted on [Google's code](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-maven-plugin/) and can now be found on [github](http://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin).

Comment: Thx for help, Do you know if i can run multiple jmeter tests with any other plugin?

Comment: @user253202 Actually, there is the maven-jmeter-plugin. See my update.

Comment: Thx but i've decided to edit patch you've linked in answer a little bit, so it it will work as i want )

Answer (score 2):

It is still not possible to use the chronos plugin to proces files based on a mask. It is possible to select a folder containing tests (.jmx-files), which should be good enough for most cases.